# NSArray from NSSet - Do I have to sort it myself?

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray, nsset

I've got data in an NSSet, and I need to get it into an NSArray.

Do I need to sort it myself (again, this came from Core Data) or can I get it out in a sorted order?

Comment: Part of the answer is that you can't get an NSArray out of a set in sorted order, so either you've got to sort it yourself, or when you get the MutableArray out of Core Data hang on to a copy once you build the set, so you can use that sorted copy where necessary.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can specify a sort when you retrieve data with an `NSFetchRequest` by setting the `sortDescriptors` property to an array of `NSSortDescriptor`s. But if you already have it in an `NSSet` and don't want to make another fetch request, you can use:

```
[[theSet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

It'll create an interim `NSArray` when you call `allObjects` and then another sorted array afterwards, so it's not 100% efficient, but the overhead should be negligible for reasonably-sized data sets (and certainly less than the cost of sorting).

### Edit

Actually, I was wrong - NSSet has the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method too. So you can just call `[theSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]` and do it all in one go.

Comment: So with the descriptor :
'NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [theSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];'

Answer (score 8):

You've got to sort it yourself, but it's not very hard...

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Sprocket" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortVariable" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];   
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];    
self.sprocketArray = mutableFetchResults;

[sortDescriptors release];
[sortDescriptor release];
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
```

Comment: you are saying that the OP would have to sort the data himself but you are providing a sample that is using CoreData's NSSortDecriptior functionality -- I would rephrase the answer and say; let CoreData do the sorting for you while fetching the data